# Deprecating FB Login Support on Android Embedded Browsers

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, deprecation-warning, react-native-fbsdk

**Got an alert from the Facebook developers console.**

We’ve been monitoring an increase in phishing attempts on Android embedded browsers, also known as WebViews. Because of this, we will no longer support this method of Facebook Login and your users will not be able to log in using Android embedded browsers beginning October 5, 2021. Until then, we will continue to prevent access to Facebook Login on embedded browsers for certain users we deem high-risk in an effort to prevent malicious activity.

To avoid a disrupted user experience, please use the following checklist:

Ensure that you have upgraded to version 8.2.0 (or later) of the Facebook SDK for Android. If your app is built to target Android 11 (API level 30) and your users are on Android 11, alternative non-webview login mechanisms provided by the SDK will not work unless you upgrade to or past 8.2.0.

Ensure that you are NOT setting LoginBehavior=WEB_VIEW_ONLY.

In my react native application, I'm using 'react-native-fbsdk v3.0.0' which is the latest published package.

Using version 3.0.0, I get FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION = safeExtGet('facebookSdkVersion', '[7.1.0, 9)') in node modules which is lower than 8.2.0 mentioned in the alert message.

So my question is, will this deprecation affect the FB login feature in my application?

Comment: You are aware that react-native-fbsdk is archived and will not get any updates? So just because you are using the latest version doesn't mean anything. https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-fbsdk lists a fork as an alternative.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of that. I removed the 'react-native-fbsdk' package and installed react-native-fbsdk-next.  It solved my problem and getting FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION = safeExtGet('facebookSdkVersion', '9.0.+') which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks again 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As react-native-fbsdk is archived and will not get updates. It is recommended to switch to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next) library. Methods remains same so just unlink the old package and remove it , and install the react-native-fbsdk-next.